# Docker mounted directory and permission

Tags: linux, docker, container

I am running an `nginx` docker with `document root /var/www/html/`. I have mounted `/opt/app` in my host machine to `/var/www/html/` of docker. An ftp user `webftp` is created in hostmachine and is able to upload the files to `/opt/apps`.

If I upload a folder via ftp, then `www-data` user in docker is not able to write into that directory.

How to set the permissions of users in docker and host?

Answer (score 1):

Just as normal. Give write permissions to www-data on the host and it will get it on the guest (container).

Comment: the uid and gid of www-data in docker is 33 and in host uid and gid of ww-data is 504

Comment: @SmrithinNS You can use chown with numbers.